# How to calculate the daily cost based on total hours?

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

How to calculate the cost using SQL what i want is to calculate cost for a single CCODE. In this data table the cost is belong to the day (DayUID) not a particular CCODE but we can extract that for particular CCODE base on the hours of the CCODE. The mathematical calculation should be like let's say CCODE=SS1 where the DayUID=DDD1

- CCODE = SS1 is 4 hours
- CCODE total duration for DDD1 = 12 hours
- DayUID = DDD1 Cost is 2000

So Cost for SS1 basically calculate like so (4 hours / 12 hours) * 2000 = 666.67

```
DayUID | DayCost | PCODE | CCODE | Duration |
---------------------------------------------
DDD1   | 2000    | TS    | SS1   | 3        |
DDD1   | 2000    | TS    | SS1   | 1        |
DDD1   | 2000    | TS    | ST2   | 2        |
DDD1   | 2000    | P     | ST2   | 6        |
DDD2   | 3000    | P     | IH1   | 6.6      |
DDD2   | 3000    | U     | IH1   | 4        |
DDD2   | 3000    | TS    | IH2   | 1        |
DDD3   | 1200    | TU    | SC1   | 7        |
DDD3   | 1200    | P     | SC2   | 8        |
DDD3   | 1200    | U     | CMPLT | 3        |
```

Comment: Actually i have no idea how it should be...my goal is to find cost for each distinct CCODE in each of the DayUID. For example CCODE = SS1 cost in DayUID = DDD1 is  666.67 and CCODE = ST2 in DayUID= DDD1 is 1333.33 (8/12)*2000 and for CCODE = IH1 in DayUID=DDD2 is (10.6/11.6)*3000 and so on

Comment: 12 hours is the total hours in DayUID = DDD1 in DayUID=DDD2 the total hours = 11.6 and in DDD3 the total hours = 18 hours. just addup in the table

Comment: The calculation goal is total hours of distinct phase in each day divide by total hours of the day where the DayUID is the same multiply by the cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get total duration by DayUID and CCODE in a subquery:

```
  SELECT a.DayUID, 
         a.CCODE, 
         SUM(a.Duration) / b.Duration * a.DayCost
    FROM Table1 a
    JOIN (SELECT DayUID, 
                SUM(Duration) Duration 
           FROM Table1 
       GROUP BY DayUID) b 
      ON a.DayUID = b.DayUID
GROUP BY DayUID, CCODE;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/846e1/2)

Comment: straight to the point perfectly.. genius and with zillion thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking you should use a dummy aggregate like `min(b.Duration)` and `min(a.Daycost)`. On most other platforms this query would not run.

Comment: @shawnt00 You are probably right that's why when tested on another platform the code is not working...could you provide the full coding using your method that you mentioned like min(b.duraiton) etc?

Comment: @rookie_coder just just the two `min` expressions in the final calculation rather than the bare column names. It's a small change.

Comment: @shawnt00 sorry i am too new into this thing where in the code should i put that in?

Comment: `SUM(a.Duration) / MIN(b.Duration) * MIN(a.DayCost)`

Comment: @shawnt00 what if i want to round the value of the cost to 2 decimal point inside the query how to do that? currently some of the cost calculated value decimal point is too much so i want to round it to 2

Comment: `ROUND(SUM(a.Duration) / MIN(b.Duration) * MIN(a.DayCost) * 100) / 100`

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you very much this question is completely answered now - i can put them to rest